# What is right way to create multi purpose rest end point?

Tags: rest, endpoint

I want to create a rest end point but I am not sure what is right way. For example I want to expose endpoint to create account but there are multiple account type like:
**Normal account** with property name, description, and current balance
**Credit Card account** with property name, description, current balance, grace period, billing date and current outstanding. Now the confusion is, Shall I create two endpoint for each of account type? or Shall I create single end point with all the property.

Answer (score 0):

> Shall I create two endpoint for each of account type? or Shall I create single end point with all the property.

How would you do it on a web site?

You might have a single `create-account` form; you collect the information that you need from the visitor, the form is submitted to the server, and the server looks at the form details to determine what kind of account to create.  Create the account, and send back a response to the browser announcing where the web page describing the account is.  And that's fine.

You might do the same thing with multiple forms; through a series of links you guide the visitor to the form that best fits their circumstances, and then the remaining work is the same as above - the form is submitted, the server looks at the form details to determine the account to create, the account is created, the server sends back a response to the browser announcing where the web page describing the account is.  And that's also fine.

You could do the same thing with multiple forms, but have each of the forms submit using a different target URI; you could even have each form submitted to a different host!  Again, the actions taken by the host receiving the form are the same - do the work, return the result announcing where the new web page is.

Thw browser doesn't care, it's just collecting form inputs using standardized form processing rules, and then submit the result using the meta data in the form.

You'll want different code responsible for creating each of the different kinds of accounts (the "separation of concerns" idea), but it doesn't much matter if the routing of the request to that code is done purely mechanically (because you are using different URI) or "by hand".